# JAVA - MultiThread Server - Lag Between Receive And Send

Tags: java, multithreading

My Multithread UDP Server launches 100 threads at maximum. In each thread it connects to external devices and receives from each a data stream. After receiving it I have a temporal window in which I need to send to the external device an acknowledge.

### receive bit inside run().

```
byte[] receiveData = new byte[2000];
DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
```

### send bit inside run() after receive.

```
DatagramPacket reply = new DatagramPacket(sendData,sendData.length,receivePacket.getAddress(),receivePacket.getPort();
serverSocket.send(reply);
```

When running wireshark to analyse the network traffic I notice that after my server receives the data stream it doesn't send the ack package right after, it takes several seconds and several other communications with other devices until the acknowledge package is sent to the device causing timeout on the device side.

In a multithread environment the server waits for all the threads to finish before sending packets?

Because almost always the packet that goes out of server waits for the packets that come as input to server.

The socket has the same queue for reading and writing?

Thanks in advance for your help I'm going nuts! :)

Comment: How is your `serverSocket` defined?

Comment: Is creating 100 threads allows more bandwidth than Ethernet connection enables?

Comment: DatagramSocket Socket7300 = new DatagramSocket(7300);

Comment: There isn't enough context. What happens between receive and send?  Nothing in Multithreaded would make a server wait for threads to finish before sending unless you coded it that way.  And no the send and receive buffer are different.

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31910411/code2.txt @stonemetal this is what happens between receive and send

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In a multithread environment the server waits for all the threads to finish before sending packets?

No.

> The socket has the same queue for reading and writing?

No.

You must have some synchronization between threads that you've overlooked. It could even be in the receivePacket itself.

Comment: here is my server sode -> https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31910411/code.txt I'm not using synchronize anywhere. Should I? The only thing that I'm doing is every new communication I add a thread every time a thread dies I decrement the thread count. To the max of 100.

Comment: dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31910411/code.txt demonstrates a very nice copy-and-paste architecture.

Comment: Well I'm a newbie. I'm learning with the best. Can the add/decrement counter be the source of the problem?

Comment: @Thelma you really should learn how to write single threaded code before making the leap into multi threaded programs. You're missing basics like arrays without no sensible program can be written.

Comment: Thank you, @Voo could you advise me into some reference material?

Comment: @Voo what kind of arrays? The read buffer? Because I have that in the thread code dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31910411/code2.txt

Comment: @Thelma having code ala foo0, foo1,.., foo9 is always a sign of a bad code architecture and usually a sign that the user is not comfortable with data structures like arrays. The official tutorial is quite good as I understand.

Comment: @Voo I didn't use an array of sockets because only these 10 ports are available. I could have created an array of sockets. Is that what you meant?

Comment: My main issue is that I know that the whole thread from start to finish takes aprox. 531 milliseconds but when I follow the packets with wireshark I was expecting to see a less that a 1 sec interval between receiving the data and sending the acknowledge to device. But what I see is an interval of aprox 15 seconds because I get other devices communications between the receiving packet time and the sending packet time.

Comment: Is there a way I can block the other threads during the receiving and sending code of another thread? My ideia would be to block any other communication between other devices during the receive and send time of other thread...